# typedef CFString starting with __

Tags: objective-c, typedef, cfstring

```
typedef const struct __CFString * a1;
```

In the above typedef declaration says a1 is defined as a pointer to constant structure __CFString.

Here what does "__" mean?

Then I create a new definition as a2, described below.

```
typedef const struct CFString * a2;
```

So, how a1 is different from a2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the underscores in `__CFString` are part of the name, so `struct __CFString` and `struct CFString` are different types, just like `struct XXCFString` and `struct CFString` are different types.

Second, any name starting with a double underscore is reserved for the implementation. In other words, you can't use names that start with a double underscore without risking a name collision.

Here's another SO answer with more details: [What are the rules for using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier)